# how to find distance between black points in a image using image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

how to find distance between  black points in a image using image processing image is taken by web camera and it is a snap of moving belt which is cover by white paper having black dots

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0):

Lots of way of doing it.

Firstly you need to identify the dots. Use Otsu thresholding to separate foreground from background. Then convent to binary, and label connected components. Eliminate everything that is smaller or larger than a threshold, or anything that isn't roughly circular.

Then you get a list of frames, so you need a blob-following algorithm. Eliminate any stationary blob (not on the paper).

Finally output the distances based on the blob identifications.